# for each row of the column (foreach)

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, foreach

[image]

I have a data frame. In column A I want each value from index 2 to be the result of the previous value A plus B divided by 10.

```
A[2:n]<- A[1:n]+B[2:n]/10
```

How can I do this with foreach?

```
foreach (i=df$A[2:17],j=df$B[2:17])%do%
{df$A[2:17]<-1:length(i)-1+1:length(j)/10
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf <- data.frame(C = 1:3, B = 11:13)

for (i in seq_along(mydf)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    mydf$A[i] <- 0
  } else {
    mydf$A[i] <- mydf$A[i-1] + mydf$B[i] / 10
  }      
}

mydf

  C  B   A
1 1 11 0.0
2 2 12 1.2
3 3 13 2.5
```